# Width and Precision confusion C++ (beginner)

Tags: c++, width, precision

```
cout << f << "\t\t" << c << endl;
cout.precision(1);
cout.width(5);
cout << fixed;
```

I'm currently beginning programming, so pardon for the simple question. How can I apply width and precision to individual variables. On my program when I set the width and precision, it sets it for both variables.

Comment: Can you give an example? How are you setting width and precision?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  In particular, it's not clear what kind of variables you're talking about; where/how you're setting precision; etc. Please include some sample code, expected results, and actual results.

Comment: cout.width(5);
cout << fixed;
cout.precision(1);

Comment: I used fixed so that i could narrow down the decimal point to one for the celsius variable. However, the precision also applied to the Farhenheit variable and eliminated the width altogether for some reason,

Comment: Bear in mind you're not setting width and precision on the *variables*, you're setting them on the *stream*.

Comment: I put the code up. When I run the program, my Fahrenheit to Celsius table comes up, but with the Precision applied to both columns on the table. If I'm not applying the width and precision to the variables, than how would I do so rather than on the entire stream

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same value for width and precision, you do not need both variables. Just use one in both places. Otherwise you will need to change the values individually. One way to easily access both is to put them in a struct.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I apply width and precision to individual variables.

You need to:

1. Get the current width and precision. Save them locally.

   ```
   std::streamsize cur_width = cout.width();
   std::streamsize cur_precision = cout.precision();
   ```
2. Set the width and precision for a variable.

   ```
   cout.width(new_width);
   cout.precision(new_precision);
   ```
3. Output the variable.

   ```
   cout << number;
   ```
4. Reset the width and precision to what they used to be:

   ```
   cout.width(cur_width);
   cout.precision(cur_precision);
   ```

Comment: 5. Output the other variable: `cout << "\t\t" << c << endl;`